# Dynamic Multi-select with checkbox Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have two issues here:

1st issue:[image: 1st problem screen]

I want the selected item names to be displayed in the "None selected" part, like this [Example](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ekd8P)
Right now, only the first item is displayed if it is selected or else it is "None Selected" even if multiple items are selected.

Here is the js code of this: [JS Code for multiselect dropdown](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js)

And here is the HTML code :

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="rolename">Add Addons</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select id="dates-field2" data-role="addonsinput" class="multiselect-ui form-control" name="addons[0]" id="trigger3" data-role="multipleselect" multiple="multiple">
           @foreach($addons as $addon)
              <option value="{{$addon->addonid}}">{{$addon->addon_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

2nd Issue:
[image: 2nd problem screen]

I am creating the fields dynamically in HTML using this JS:

```js
$(function() {
    // Remove button 
    $(document).on(
        'click',
        '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-horizontal [data-role="remove"]',
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('.form-horizontal').remove();
        }
    );
    // Add button 
 var i = 1;
    $(document).on(
        'click',
        '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-horizontal [data-role="add"]',
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
            new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-horizontal:first-child').clone();
   
            new_field_group.find('input').each(function(){

    if(this.name == 'tags[0]'){
     $(this).tagsinput('destroy');
     $(this).tagsinput('removeAll');
     this.name = this.name.replace('[0]','['+i+']');
     var new_container = $(this).closest('[class="form-group"]');
     new_container.find(".bootstrap-tagsinput:first").remove();
    } 
    else {
     $(this).val('');
    }
            });
   i+=1;
            container.append(new_field_group);
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-body ">
  <form action="" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }} 
   <div data-role="dynamic-fields">
     <div class="form-horizontal">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enter Dish Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name1" name="Name[]" required data-rule-minlength="2">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enter Dish Price(In Rupees)</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Price" name="Price[]" required data-rule-minlength="2">
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select Food Type</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
           <select id="select1" class="form-control" name="select[]" required>
            @foreach($types as $type)
            <option value="{{$loop->iteration}}">{{$type->food_type_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
           <select>
            <p class="help-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="xyz"><i class="md md-info"></i></p>
              </div>
          </div>
         </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-6"> 
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enter Associated Tags</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                                   <input type="text" value="" name="tags[0]" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Tags" />
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        
                       
                   </div>
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Dish Description</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input name="Description[]" id="field-value" class="form-control">
                   </div>
               </div> 
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-sm-6 contacts">
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="rolename">Add Addons</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <select id="dates-field2" data-role="addonsinput" class="multiselect-ui form-control" name="addons[0]" id="trigger3" data-role="multipleselect" multiple="multiple">
                           @foreach($addons as $addon)
                            <option value="{{$addon->addonid}}">{{$addon->addon_name}}</option>
                           @endforeach
                          </select>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <div class="checkbox checkbox-styled">
                            <label><em>Half Plate Price(if any)</em>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="" class="trigger2" id="trigger2" name="question"> 
                            </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                            <div id="hidden_fields2" class="hidden_fields2" style="display:none;">
                                                             <input type="text" id="hidden_field2" name="Price2[]" placeholder="Please Enter" class="form-control"> 
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                       </div>
                                                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <div class="checkbox checkbox-styled">
                            <label><em>Quarter Plate Price</em>
                             <input type="checkbox" value="" class="trigger" id="trigger" name="question"> 
                            </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                            <div id="hidden_fields" class="hidden_fields" style="display:none;">
                                                             <input type="text" id="hidden_field" name="Price3[]" placeholder="Please Enter" class="form-control" > 
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                       </div>
                                                    </div>
             <br>
                   <button class="btn btn-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Field" data-role="remove">
              Delete Item
             </button>
             <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add More Field" data-role="add">
              Add More Items
             </button>
            </div><!-- /div.form-inline -->
           </div>   <!-- /div[data-role="dynamic-fields"] --><br>
           <div class="form-group">   
               <button type="submit" name="submit" href="#" class="btn ink-reaction btn-raised btn-primary">Submit Items</button>
              </div><!--end .form-group -->
          </form>
         </div><!--end .row -->
           </div><!--end .card-body -->
```

Right now, the duplicate fields are exactly duplicating the multiple checkbox from the first one. I want it to be in "None Selecting" mode when it is created dynamically.

Any leads would be helpful. Thank you in advance.